# Cannot install Facebook Android SDK using Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I need to integrate with Facebook. So I am installing SDK using Gradle following [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). But when I run my app to update Gradle, it is throwing error. How can I fix it to install sdk?

This is my Gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.facebooksdk.facebooksdk"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

This is the screenshots of error message:

[image]

[image]

Why I cannot install it? I am using Android Studio version 1.4. How can I install Facebook SDK using Gradle in Android Studio? I exactly followed the instructions from Facebook.

Comment: Its not the problem of facebook your not having latest SDK update.

Comment: you can try changing your dependencies to 23.2.1 to be the same as the ones used by facebook?

Comment: Try with `Install Repository and Sync Project` for all exceptions.

Comment: open SDK manager and update your Android SDK and replace facebook 4.+ on     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

Comment: update android studio to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

you forgot other libraries in your gradle.

try to use

```
compile "com.android.support:design:23.2.1"
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```